# Regex - Remove a value from a string using Javascript/Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a text variable in the following format -

```
value1|34|value2|45|value3|67|value4|687|
```

Now I just have the text '`value3`' with me and I've to remove that value along with its associated number from the above string. After removing it I've to get -

```
value1|34|value2|45|value4|687|
```

Note: The numbers in the pipelines are prefixed with its value string. Ex - Value|56|. So if I've to remove a value I've to remove it along with its number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
var s = "value1|34|value2|45|value3|0000|value4|687|";
var r = "value3";

s = s.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\|)" + r + "\\|\\d+"), "")
```

Includes start-guard (wont match xxxvalue3)

Comment: This is removing the pipeline before the value. For example, after you remove value3 I'm getting - value1|34|value2|45value4|687|

Comment: If the value has some special character like this - "Test: (Has- Characters)" it is not working. I'm not able to figure out which of the character is causing the issue.

Comment: I guess parentheses () is causing the issue. How to fix it?

Comment: Changed re; to use a string that contain characters that form part of re syntax you must escape it; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could benefit from using something like JSON as a storage format instead.

```
'value1|34|value2|45|value3|67|value4|687|'.replace(/value3\|\d+\|/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = 'value1|34|value2|45|value3|67|value4|687|',
    remove = 'value3',
    result = input.replace(RegExp(remove + '\\|\\d+\\|'), '');
console.log(result); // 'value1|34|value2|45|value4|687|'
```

Comment: Not working :(. I'm still getting the same original string after replacing it.

Comment: If the value has some special character like this - "Test: (Has- Characters)" it is not working. I'm not able to figure out which of the character is causing the issue.

Comment: I guess parentheses () is causing the issue. How to fix it?

Comment: Replace `\d` (which only matches digits) with a character class that would match everything you want to match, e.g. `[0-9a-zA-Z\(\)\s-]`, or  simply use `[^|]`.